# C# Entity Framework: making sure each entry is unique

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm making an API call with C#, getting back a JSON, breaking it down into nested objects, breaking each object into fields and putting the fields into an SQL Server table.

There is one field (OnlineURL) which should be unique.

What is an efficient way of achieving this goal? I currently make a database call for every nested object I pull out of the JSON and then use an if statement. But this is not efficient.

Comment: create a unique index constraint on the column in the db. Update your question with the correct RDBMs tag you are using and you might get some more help.

Comment: Regarding "breaking it down into nested objects, breaking each object into fields...", just in case you didnt know, for this, you could just use serialization. Of course that assumes your json is well-formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Database Layer**
Creating a unique index/constraint for the OnlineURL field in the database will enforce the field being unique no matter what system/codebase references it. This will result in applications erroring on inserts of new records where the OnlineURL already exists or updating record X to an OnlineURL that is already being used by record Y.

**Application Layer**
What is the rule when OnlineURL already exists? Do you reject the data? Do you update the matching row? Maybe you want to leverage a stored procedure that will insert a new row based on OnlineURL or update the existing one. This will turn a 2 query process into a single query, which will have an impact on large scale inserts.

Assuming your application is serial and the only one working against the database. You could also keep a local cache of OnlineURLs for use during your loop, read in the list once from the database, check each incoming record against it and then add each new OnlineURL you insert into the list. To read in the initial list is only a single query and each comparison is done in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index for that field and it will be.

It is necessary to check the uniqueness and that can't be fullfilled if you don't query the data. That means you will have to check the entire data in that column. Your first option is to improve the query with an index with a fill factor of 80 so you can avoid unnecessary page splits caused by the inserts.

Another option is to use caching and depends on your setup.
You could load the entire column in memory and check for the uniqueness there. Or you could use a distributed cache like Redis. Either way analyze the complexity costs and probably you'll that the index is the most ergonomic option.

Comment: Do you mean that making the database call for each object will be efficient, or that it will be unnecessary?

Comment: Indexed the column with a fill factor of 80. 

Now getting "OriginalValues cannot be used for entities in the Added state." errors

Comment: Sounds like a different issue and probably related to data. Can you debug the exception? How did you create the index?